# Fetching correct parameter value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an parameter table which stores multiple parameters. So this is used to drive the query. Below is the parameter table:

```
P_ID  P_NAME              P_VALUE
1     BASE_CURRENCY_FLG   Y
2     BASE_CURRENCY       EUR
3     GLOBAL_CURRENCY     USD
```

I have one transaction table **TRXN** which stores transaction amount and transaction currency.

I also have **currency_rate** table which has columns CUR1, CUR2, CUR1_CUR2_CONV_RATE.

So my requirement is whenever **BASE_CURRENCY_FLG** is N, we have to fetch the amount and currency value from trxn table and convert into USD using currency_rate table.

Similarly if **BASE_CURRENCY_FLG** is Y then we have to convert the transaction amount to EUR.

We have to write this in SQL block(not PL/SQL). Database is Oracle. Any help will be highly appreciated.

We tried using CASE statement but unable to achieve the desired result.
Below are the sample data:

**TRXN Table**

```
TXN_ID          TXN_AMT     TXN_CURRENCY
100             45564.23    EUR
180             2908        INR
232             654         USD
198             1223        AUD
```

**CURRENCY_RATE table**

```
C_ID       CUR1       CUR2     CUR1_CUR2_CONV_RATE
1          INR        USD      64.2
2          INR        EUR      80.2
3          EUR        USD      1.23
4          USD        EUR      0.81
5          USD        AUD      1.28
```

Comment: Table structures and sample data would be helpful.

Comment: I have added sample data and table

Answer (score -1):

I have difficulties in imagining what you have. Words are here, but I'm more a *visual* type who prefers seeing table description and sample data.

Saying that you are supposed to convert currencies - how would you do that? What are those `CUR1` and `CUR2`? EUR and USD? What exactly `CUR1_CUR2_CONV_RATE` means? `CUR1/CUR2` or opposite or ...?

Therefore, this might - or might not - be one of the possible options. It unions two similar `SELECT` statements; distinction is based on `BASE_CURRENCY_FLG` value as well as what you should do with `CUR1_CUR2_CONV_RATE`. Fix it, if necessary.

```
SELECT t.tr_amount, t.tr_currency * cr.cur1_cur2_conv_rate
  FROM trxn t JOIN currency_rate cr ON cr.cur1 = tr.tr_currency
 WHERE 'N' = (SELECT base_currency_flg FROM param)
UNION
SELECT t.tr_amount, t.tr_currency / cr.cur1_cur2_conv_rate
  FROM trxn t JOIN currency_rate cr ON cr.cur1 = tr.tr_currency
 WHERE 'Y' = (SELECT base_currency_flg FROM param)
```

**[EDIT]**

OK, now it makes sense. Here's a query; actual *useful* code begins at line 22.

```
SQL> with trxn (txn_id, txn_amt, txn_currency) as
  2    (select 100, 45564.23, 'EUR' from dual union
  3     select 180, 2908    , 'INR' from dual union
  4     select 232, 654     , 'USD' from dual union
  5     select 198, 1223    , 'AUD' from dual union
  6     --
  7     select 500, 100, 'EUR' from dual union
  8     select 501, 100, 'INR' from dual
  9    ),
 10  currency_rate (c_id, cur1, cur2, cur1_cur2_conv_rate) as
 11    (select 1, 'INR', 'USD', 64.2 from dual union
 12     select 2, 'INR', 'EUR', 80.2 from dual union
 13     select 3, 'EUR', 'USD', 1.23 from dual union
 14     select 4, 'USD', 'EUR', 0.81 from dual union
 15     select 5, 'USD', 'AUD', 1.28 from dual
 16    ),
 17  param (p_id, p_name, p_value) as
 18    (select 1, 'BASE_CURRENCY_FLG', 'Y' from dual union  --> while testing, change Y -> N
 19     select 2, 'BASE_CURRENCY', 'EUR'   from dual union  --  and vice versa
 20     select 3, 'GLOBAL_CURRENCY', 'USD' from dual
 21    )
 22  select t.txn_id,
 23         t.txn_amt,
 24         t.txn_currency,
 25         t.txn_amt * cr.cur1_cur2_conv_rate converted,
 26         cr.cur2
 27    from trxn t join currency_rate cr on cr.cur1 = t.txn_currency
 28   where     'Y' = (select p_value
 29                      from param
 30                     where p_name = 'BASE_CURRENCY_FLG')
 31         and cr.cur2 = 'EUR'
 32  union
 33  select t.txn_id,
 34         t.txn_amt,
 35         t.txn_currency,
 36         t.txn_amt * cr.cur1_cur2_conv_rate converted,
 37         cr.cur2
 38    from trxn t join currency_rate cr on cr.cur1 = t.txn_currency
 39   where     'N' = (select p_value
 40                      from param
 41                     where p_name = 'BASE_CURRENCY_FLG')
 42         and cr.cur2 = 'USD'
 43  order by txn_id;

    TXN_ID    TXN_AMT TXN  CONVERTED CUR
---------- ---------- --- ---------- ---
       180       2908 INR   233221,6 EUR
       232        654 USD     529,74 EUR
       501        100 INR       8020 EUR

SQL>
```

If BASE_CURRENCY_FLG is changed to 'N', then the result is

```
    TXN_ID    TXN_AMT TXN  CONVERTED CUR
---------- ---------- --- ---------- ---
       100   45564,23 EUR 56044,0029 USD
       180       2908 INR   186693,6 USD
       500        100 EUR        123 USD
       501        100 INR       6420 USD
```

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. I have added sample data and table structure in the question.